# Why is Firefox so slow?

Tags: firefox

After updrading to ubuntu 12.04 LTS (on a DELL Studio XPS) firefox is not working like it should. It takes a lot of time before launching (> 20 seconds) and the application is abnormally slow, not to say "totally unusable"

I already tried to remove it and reinstall it, did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Try launching it from the terminal by typing `firefox -safe-mode`

Comment: I've launched it in safe-mode and checked all options (disabled all add-ons / reset toolbars and controls, ....). It works now. I assume it came from one add-on or from old settings. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 11):

**Possible Reasons:**

1. Too many tabs open on start-up
2. Too many add-ons installed
3. Problematic add-ons

**Solutions:**

- If you think you may have too many tabs open at start-up, see if using the new feature, "Don't load tabs until selected", helps any.

[image: enabling don't load until selected]

- Having too many add-ons installed can greatly affect Firefox's performance. **Try removing some unnecessary add-ons.**
- Check for any add-on that is causing a problem. First open Firefox in [safe mode](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-use-mozilla-firefox-in-safe-mode/) by going to help menu and selecting "Restart with add-ons disabled". If performace of Firefox suddenly improves in safe mode that means one of your add-ons is culprit. To find the problematic add-on disable add-ons one by one until the issue is resolved. Hare's a list of problematic extensions at [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problematic_extensions).

If the above options don't help, try creating a new user profile.

Make sure that Firefox is closed. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:

`firefox -profilemanager`

Create a new profile and see if that solves your problem.

[image: choose user profile]

If nothing works then you can reinstall Firefox. You can do it by running these commands in terminal.

`sudo apt-get purge firefox`

sudo apt-get install firefox

**Useful extensions to improve Firefox performance:**

- [Memory Restart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memory-restart/)

  Memory Restart is a very handy add-on to keep an eye on memory usage of Firefox and restart if memory usage gets to high.

**Additional sources:**

- [Performance best practices in extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Performance_best_practices_in_extensions)
- [Firefox is slow](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Firefox%20is%20slow) from Mozilla Help
- [High memory usage](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/High%20memory%20usage) from Mozilla help
- [High CPU usage](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Firefox%20consumes%20a%20lot%20of%20CPU%20resources) from Mozilla help
- [Firefox takes a long time to start up](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-takes-long-time-start-up) from Mozilla help

Answer (score 1):

**Some reasons**

Slow Firefox start-up can be explained by at least the following factors that I know of:

- Growing size of the internal Firefox Database
- Add-ons that are slowing down Firefox

**Solution 1 - Optimise databases**

To optimise the databases of Firefox, you can use the following script: [Firefox optimisation for Linux](http://www.berthon.eu/wiki/perso%3adump%3amess?s=sqlite3#optimisation_for_linux) It simply run optimisation command on the databases that it founds in your user directory. You need to install sqlite3 though, it's available by default in the UBuntu's repositoies.b

**Solution2 - an add-on might be slowing down Firefox**

For the add-ons, try disabling them one by one and restart Firefox each time. If one is making Firefox much slower then you have to assess: "do I really need this add-on?"