# What's the state of hardware accelerated HTML5 video on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, video, flash, html5, hardware-acceleration

Flash hardware acceleration never really worked in Linux due to various APIs (VDPAU, VA API, and what not), buggy drivers, and end-of support from Adobe for Flash on Linux.

Recently several sites, such as youtube, switched to HTML5 video.
Is it possible to have accelerated HTML5 video with Firefox and an Intel integrated video chip (such as e.g. Intel HD Graphics 4XXX)? What steps are needed?

*edit*: note that my question specifically targets HTML5 hardware acceleration, and not Flash Acceleration or other forms of graphics accelerations in Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Firefox support hardware acceleration on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140007/does-firefox-support-hardware-acceleration-on-ubuntu)

Comment: indeed; but note that my question specifically targets HTML5