# Why firefox getting slow?

Tags: firefox, pipelight

A couple days ago I was trying to enable silverlight in firefox with pipelight.  I followed the instructions here http://www.infoworld.com/article/2697813/install-silverlight-alternative-pipelight-in-ubuntu-14-04.html

It wasn't working for me so I disabled it and uninstalled.   Since then firefox will sometime act up when visiting sites with flash.  I don't know what pipelight did to screw up my firefox.  Any idea on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Firefox so slow?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133737/why-is-firefox-so-slow)

Comment: Because of pipelight I don't think that there's anything in [Why is Firefox so slow?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133737/why-is-firefox-so-slow) that will answer this question.